# How can I vectorized a function when one parameter is a dataframe that shouldn't be vectorized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I need to vectorize functions manipulating panda Dataframes or Series to decrease processing time.

The problem is that some of the parameters of the vectorized function must not be vectorized.

Let's see an example with the following code. I create a series that will be processed as a vector.

```py
Values = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(3, 1)), columns=['V'], index = ['mean', 'std', 'delta'])
```

```
Values
        V
mean    0.885185
std     0.262265
delta   0.790134
```

Then I have a model, it is linked to Values by 'cpt' columns but doesn't have the same shape at all.

```py
Model = pd.DataFrame([['JAVA','mean',10],['Python','std',5],['JS','sqrt',6],['JAVA','dif',3]],
                  columns = ['Language', 'cpt' , 'Id'])
```

```
Model
    Language    cpt     Id
0   JAVA        mean    10
1   Python      std     5
2   JS          sqrt    6
3   JAVA        dif     3
```

I need to find the Id corresponding in the model to the cpt for each value.
I write the function as if I can vectorize it.

```py
def findId(Values, Model):
    return (Model[Model.cpt == Values].Id.values)
```

The output of the function is then

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

because the Model parameter is also vectorized.

How can I do to pass the parameter 'Model' to the function and that it will not be considered as the same size parameter?

I could write a loop like that one but it's the initial problem I'm trying to tackle:

```py
def loopfindId(Values, Model):
    ScaleNbrs = []
    for i in range (len(Values)):
        ScaleNbrs.append(findId(Values.index[i], Model))
    return ScaleNbrs
```

```py
loopfindId(Values, Model)
[array([10], dtype=int64), array([5], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64)]
```

However, even if I get almost the desired result  it is very slow because I have to process that way a lot of times in the algorithm and it has to process it a million times.

I'm not 100% sure of the results I desire from that step but after getting the Id for each Value I will have to check if the value is inside a row of a table depending on the Id.
The DataFrame of the Id will look likes:

```py
Scale = pd.DataFrame([['LevelA', 0, 0.3, 10],['LevelB', 0.3, 1, 10],
                      ['LevelA', 0, 0.2, 3],['LevelB', 0.2, 0.6, 3],['LevelC', 0.6, 1, 3]],
                  columns = ['Level', 'lowerBound', 'upperBound', 'Id'])
```

```
      Level     lowerBound  upperBound  Id
0     LevelA    0.0         0.3         10
1     LevelB    0.3         1.0         10
2     LevelA    0.0         0.2         3
3     LevelB    0.2         0.6         3
4     LevelC    0.6         1.0         3
```

Then I need to know in which level is the Value and also other pieces of information about the row and its position respectively to the other levels available In the Scale DataFrame.
That's why I would like to introduce the DataFrame as a parameter of a function but it may have a better way to do it.

Comment: `Model.set_index('cpt').join(Values)`?

Comment: or `Model.loc[Model['cpt'].isin(Values.index), 'Id']` IIUC..?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an expected output but based on what you wrote I think an index merge is what you want

```
Model.set_index('cpt').merge(Values, left_index=True, right_index=True)

     Language  Id         V
mean     JAVA  10  0.754550
std    Python   5  0.931809
```

An `isin` lookup might work as well if merge is taking too much memory

`Model.loc[Model['cpt'].isin(Values.index)]`

```
  Language   cpt  Id
0     JAVA  mean  10
1   Python   std   5
```

Comment: I updated the post to provide a better view of the expected output, I think the problem with the merge as with the join, I may end up with a huge DataFrame, heavy to process